# Django Form.Errors message is not showing and not printing in console

Tags: html, django, forms

I am learning django forms right now. I can not see the output of the error in the website as a text message, it only shows as a pop-up message with the default error message even though I set my own error message. Also, my console is not printing anything after

```
if form.is_valid():
```

This is my views.py file:

```
def forms(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Forms(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            print("hello")
            form.save()
            print(form.cleaned_data)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thank_you')
    else: 
        form = Forms()
    

    return render(request, "form/index.html", {
        'form': form
    })

def thank_you(request):
    return render(request, 'form/thankyou.html')
```

And here's the html file

```
<html lang='en'>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
  <form action="/thank-you" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.name.label_tag}} <br>
    {{form.name}} <br>
    {{form.name.errors}}
    <button type="submit">Send</button> 

  </form>
```

Comment: "_it only shows as a pop-up message_", I think you talk about the browser doing some validation there. Try adding the `novalidate` attribute to your form tag: `<form action="/thank-you" method="POST" novalidate>` does that do what you expect?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your template to show error message:

```py
{% if form.errors %}
    {% for field in form %}
        {% for error in field.errors %}
            <strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

And [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48620812/django-forms-custom-error-message-in-views) is solution for custom error message.